# Suggest tutorial for ASP.NET MVC with json for beginners

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have started learing json for developing high end web applications in asp.net mvc.
Please suggest some tutorials or links to understand it.

Comment: http://www.akhildeshpande.com/2011/08/simple-jquery-getjson-example-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 3):

The following should be helpful

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124541/Working-on-JSON-objects-in-jQuery-and-MVC
http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx

Comment: I m working on mvc2 .. which jquery/javascript version compatible with them ?

Comment: jQuery doesn't depent on mvc version so you can use latest version as well

Answer (score 1):

this is an amazing video tutorial source. I watched all the videos and it helped me a lot.....
[PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvc4-building)